# Copy the contents of specific worksheets to a master worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that has several pages:

- From 1 to 31 (1 per day of the month);
- 1 master page (where I gather some data for each day);
- 1 page with graphics based on the master page.

Is there an automatic way to copy all data from all pages (1 per day (ignoring your own master sheet and chart sheet) to the master page? 
• Copying only from ranges A12: B18, F12:F18 and putting one data below the other? A7 has the title of each page (day of the month), and in A8 it has the name of the user, I would like these 2 data also to come as columns next to the data of the master page.

I know I could give an optimized one in this worksheet for the user to fill everything in just 1 spreadsheet, however it will not be intuitive for them (and consequently will bring many fill errors if I do this). I think of doing a google form in the future for this case, but I would like to implement this script to do this automation at the moment, and I will take that same code to several other spreadsheets that are in this horrible work format (it is easy for the user only fills in the data on a daily basis, but for the user who will compile the whole month (joining the data of every day in a master worksheet), it is extremely labor intensive.

I think someone already has some script ready for this, because it is very common to find spreadsheets in this format

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script to combine multiple worksheets to a master sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749665/script-to-combine-multiple-worksheets-to-a-master-sheet)

Comment: @Cooper I can not comment on this post, it requires 50 reputation. I created a test worksheet with your script, but it displays the following error in the macro "combineDataForAllSheets": TypeError: Can not call the "hideSheet" method of null. (line 5, file "Code")

Comment: See my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment, here is the pertinent section of code:

```
  var excl=['Globals','Form Responses 1','Form Responses 2'];//These were my choices you probably need to change them
  var masterSheet="Master";
  for(var i=0;i<excl.length;i++) {ss.getSheetByName(excl[i]).hideSheet()}
```

Did you fill in the appropriate sheet names that you wish to exclude from the process?

Try This:

```
function combineDataForUser616324() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh=ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  msh.clearContents();
  var xshts=['Globals','Form Responses 1','Form Responses 2','Master'];
  var ashts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var ia=0;ia<ashts.length;ia++) {
    if(xshts.indexOf(ashts[ia].getName())==-1) {
      var sh=ashts[ia];
      var name=sh.getName();
      var rlA=sh.getRangeList(['A12:F18','A7','A8']).getRanges();
      var vA=rlA[0].getValues();
      vA=vA.map(function(r){return [r[0],r[1],r[5]]});
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
        if(i==0) {
          vA[i].splice(0,0,rlA[2].getValue(),rlA[1].getValue());
        }else{
          vA[i].splice(0,0,'','');
        }
      }
      msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
    }
  }
}
```

or if you like using Array Functions you can do it this way:

```
function combineDataForUser616324() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh=ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  msh.clearContents();
  var xshts=['Globals','Form Responses 1','Form Responses 2','Master'];
  var ashts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var ia=0;ia<ashts.length;ia++) {
    if(xshts.indexOf(ashts[ia].getName())==-1) {
      var sh=ashts[ia];
      var name=sh.getName();
      var rlA=sh.getRangeList(['A12:F18','A7','A8']).getRanges();
      var vA=rlA[0].getValues();
      vA=vA.map(function(r){return [r[0],r[1],r[5]]});
      vA=vA.map(function(r,i){
        if(i==0) {
          r.splice(0,0,rlA[2].getValue(),rlA[1].getValue());//this returns shallow copy so cannot return it
          return r;
        }else{
          r.splice(0,0,'','');//same thing here
          return r;
        }
      });
      /*  
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
        if(i==0) {
          vA[i].splice(0,0,rlA[2].getValue(),rlA[1].getValue());
        }else{
          vA[i].splice(0,0,'','');
        }
      }
      */
      msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good morning @Cooper,your script works perfectly.The error I was getting was due to what you mentioned yourself(not having the name of the worksheets to be deleted).However,it does not work properly in this case that I have,I believe it is because there are blanks between some cells.Is there a way to adpt it to fetch only fixed intervals?instead of fetching through the header of the master worksheet?For eg:range A7(this cell contains the title,it would be desirable to repeat) and range A12: B18?I understood your code up to line 11,after that step it got too complex for me 2 be able to edit.Tks

Comment: On a spreadsheet, show my what the master sheet should look like. And what sections of the individual sheets look like and I'll make the modification for you.

Comment: I made this example of how the data should be displayed in the master table(using formula (Without script). The fields to be exported to the master table are highlighted in red.


https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_ePOeBrem4-hZkJoTE9IKgqvuXdPrHazDpbUIHVabg/edit?usp=sharing

These are just examples with dummy data, the original worksheet has a lot more data and pages, but by working on those fields I think I can add the other required fields. Thanks @Cooper